# Using SQL Server Extended Events to audit table access

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, extended-events

Is it possible to monitor table access using SQL Server 2008 R2 Extended Events (EE)? We need to monitor any table reads, updates or inserts for one table. From what I can gather, it should be possible to monitor Selects via table lock events with EE. It's a SQL 2008 R2 server, standard edition so we can't use the auditing feature that's available with Enterprise.

Answer (score -1):

I'd personally use SQL Audit (which, incidentally, is built on a backbone of extended events). You can audit the operations you're looking for directly without having to resort to hacks like looking for certain kinds of locks. Look up the documentation in BOL for "CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION" for a quick example.

Comment: Please see the last line in the question. "standard edition so we can't use the auditing feature that's available with Enterprise."

Comment: You're right; I missed that. I still wouldn't try to use any sort of second-order effects like certain kinds of locks being obtained on the tables in question.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @ZachSaucier this answer is clearly not a question. Please be careful when reviewing the low quality post queue.